# TV titles: Split a list into text from a CSV document using Animation Nodes

Tags: text-object, animation-nodes

I have a Spreadsheet list that is sorted into columns of attributes (Story name, Journalist Name, Talent name, Talent Occupation etc.). This is then sorted into order of appearance by its row, so that upon a frame change I will generate a new graphic item from the columns.

[image: CSV list of tv titles]

So far I can reduce the list down to seperate items per row, but I can't figure how to split the items on to their own lines? So that they appear like this:

[image: preffered outcome]

Also I want to control the font size per line, can this be done to the single text object?

Finally I want to allocate position information based on the column the item comes from. For example the column 1 and 2 appear in the bottom left but item 6 appeared on the top left. I considered using Empty objects as adjustable hooks but I don't know how to integrate them based on column info?

Comment: Can you clarify your last point?

Comment: Each group or set of words is allocated to a unique column. e.g. Column 01 (title) should be placed in the lower left corner where I place an empty. Column 06 (Top of Frame Info) should be placed in the upper left corner where I place a different empty.  The problem is, how can I use the column number to decide the location of each set?

Comment: I edited the answer, is this what you want?

Comment: Thank you, I have a lot more understanding now. Your answer was very close to what I hope to achieve. I will add an answer for completeness but accept yours as the solution. I always have trouble understanding loops and how they achieve iteration of output, so this will help lots ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Double Line

---

To make the text be formatted on two lines, you can replace the `,` with a line break special character as follows:

[image: Double Line]

### Different Sized lines

---

Blender doesn't allow various sizes for the same text object, what you need to do is separate each of the lines as follows:

[image: Different Sized Lines]

### Column Location

First, I would make a classifier loop that classify each column, For instance, I classified this text into names and titles.

[image: Classifier]

Then we join names and titles using a line break (Or possibly make them different object if you want them to have different sizes), and then output the text to a text object as follows:

[image: Final Column]

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the help, it seems so simple compared to all the complex Motion Graphics AN gets applied to, but it would really help my workflow.

Comment: How are you assigning the empty to the Text Instance Transform? I see that you define "Objects From Group" but how does the Text Output know which empty to use?

Comment: @3pointedit I add the empties to a blender group and get them from the Objects From Group node. They are associated in order, so the first empty controls the Names and the second controls the Title.